# How to seperate data with a line break

Tags: python, html, wsgi

I am trying to figure out how to separate data i'm showing on a HTML page which is coming from a tuple in python.

Python:

```
    callComments = (interface.list_comments(db,10))

    content = { comments': '<p>%s</p>' % commentString,
              }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class = "comments">
 <p>These are some comments:</p>
 %comments
 </div>
```

has this output:

```
(13, 'mary@where.com', 'hello', ' amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\nlabore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut') (12, 'mary@where.com', 'hello', 'orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor i') (11, 'jim@there.com', 'hello', 'consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\nlabore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\nex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat\nnulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui of')
```

But I want it to output like this:

```
(13, 'mary@where.com', 'hello', ' amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\nlabore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut')

(12, 'mary@where.com', 'hello', 'orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor i')

(11, 'jim@there.com', 'hello', 'consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\nlabore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\nex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat\nnulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui of')
```

What is the easiest, most effective way to do this?

Comment: 1. Your Python has a syntax error. 2. You don't really explain how you render the HTML. What framework / template language are you using?

Comment: Was that a hard question to answer? And that output is kinda silly. That's not *really* what you want is it?

Comment: And I just realized, you don't even show the complete code. This question is not really answerable in it's current state, it involves too much guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow loop over the tuple. The best way of doing that depends on what tools you are using, particularly the template language and framework.

If you aren't using a template language or framework, then the correct answer is : "Use a good webframework, with some sort of template language".

If you for some reason refuse to use good practices, then do this:

```
callComments = interface.list_comments(db,10)

content = { 'comments': ' '.join('<p>%s</p>' % repr(x) for x in callComments),
          }
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I'm very new so i'm sorry I didn't give enough information. Do you think you could explain what this is actually doing? I'd rather learn then just get the answer. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @user2288946: I'll tell you if you answer my questions above. ;-)